# Google Apps Script function Splice not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to Javascript but not to coding. I love to start with clean simple examples. I am trying to insert items into an array using splice. Examples abound! They all get the same result!

```
function ArrTest(){ 
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    Logger.log("before " + fruits.length);

fruits.splice(2, 0, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
    Logger.log("after " + fruits.length);
}
```

When I try to run I get the error on the "fruits.splice..." line:

> TypeError: Cannot find function splice in object [object Array].

I am on Windows 10 (up to date) using Chrome (latest version). Every time I search for this error I get more examples showing how great this works! Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot - I am using Chrome, open a google sheet from Drive and then Tools/Script editor:
[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you typing this code? You said `Slice` in title, then `splice`... Then `fruits`..`fruit`. Provide a screenshot of your code with the error.

Comment: This is interesting.  Writing ["a","c"].splice(1,0,"b") should make an array a,b,c but running in Chrome console version 69 it returns an empty array.  But @Rajkumar A's answer works, and if I change your Logger out for console it also works in the Chrome debugger. What do you see in the console if you enter Array.prototype.splice ?  It should print f splice() { [native code] } if supported.

Comment: Logs? What does it log? And Do you have any other variables named `fruits` in other files(as seen in your screenshot)? What about ``fruits.push("orange")`` Also try debug run.

Comment: I just created a new blank sheet and pasted the code into the editor and it works as expected! I went back to the original and I did have another copy of the fruits example. I deleted it but still got the error. I did not realize that the variables were global to that extent.

Comment: I have gone in and renamed the function and the variables but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a variable as **fruits** but error said **fruit**. **fruit** variable is undefined. Hence you might gets this error. splice works only for array object. Below code is working fine for me.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        console.log("before " + fruits.length);
    
    fruits.splice(2, 0, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
        console.log("after " + fruits.length);
```

Comment: But the error says `TypeError: Cannot find function splice in object` **[object Array].** not `undefined`

Comment: Above code is working in google apps script also. I didn't get any errors as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider this answered. Thank you all for your help and input.

Splice is working as expected. On a clean sheet with no other code, the example I posted works fine. Apparently, I had something else in another project attached to the same sheet that was causing the problem. I still do not understand exactly what, but that can be the subject for another question.